# I have two datasets of audio and text. How to split them randomly, but they have the same index for correlating audio-text?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

This is in Python. I have two datasets with audio and text in pandas. Each audio has its corresponding text in the same index. Ex, audio in index 0 has its text in index 0 in the other dataset. How do I split them for train and test randomly, but they still correspond with each other?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import shutil

audio_folder = CREMA
train_folder = "C:/Users/kevin/Documents/TugasAkhir/crema_train"
test_folder = "C:/Users/kevin/Documents/TugasAkhir/crema_test"

# Get the list of audio file paths
audio_files = [os.path.join(audio_folder, file) for file in os.listdir(audio_folder) if file.endswith(".wav")]

# Split the file paths into training and test sets
train_files_A, test_files_A, train_files_T, test_files_T = train_test_split(audio_files, audio_words, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle = True)

# # Copy or move the training files
# for file in train_files_A:
#     shutil.copy(file, train_folder)

# # Copy or move the test files
# for file in test_files_A:
#     shutil.copy(file, test_folder)
```

[This is the result after splitting the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5OfB.png)